# Parsing javascript json

Tags: javascript, python, json

I was taking json from python and then parsing using `JSON.parse`

Original function was:

```
success: function(response){
            $("#loader").addClass("hide");
            console.log(response);
            response = JSON.parse(response)// Internationalization
            response_tree = response["tree"]
            response_location = response["location"]
```

Now I added maunal json,

```
success: function(response){
            $("#loader").addClass("hide");
            response = "{'tree': [{'data': [], 'id': 'Adalaj', 'name': 'Adalaj'}, {'data': [['love, Noun', 82], ['I, Pronoun', 77], ['you, Pronoun', 71], ['ahmedabad, Noun', 128], ['instagram, Noun', 52], ['is, Verb', 60], ['fun, Noun', 71], ['riverfront, Noun', 54], ['instagood, Noun', 91],['instagram_ahmedabad, Noun', 67], ['_soi, Noun', 56]], 'id': 'Ahmedabad', 'name': 'Ahmedabad'}, {'data': [ ['beach, Noun', 130], ['alibag, Noun', 63], ['fun, Noun', 73], ['alibaug, Noun', 65]], 'id': 'Alibaug', 'name': 'Alibaug'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Anand', 'name': 'Anand'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Bhandardara', 'name': 'Bhandardara'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Bhavnagar', 'name': 'Bhavnagar'}, {'data': [['I, Pronoun', 94], ['bhuj, Noun', 110], ['india, Noun', 77], ['https, Noun', 70], ['you, Pronoun', 82], ['kutch, Noun', 67], ['madamehall, Noun', 62], ['Bhuj, Noun', 92], ['is, Verb', 100], ['it, Pronoun', 56],  ['gujarat, Noun', 63]], 'id': 'Bhuj', 'name': 'Bhuj'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Bidar', 'name': 'Bidar'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Daman', 'name': 'Daman'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Daman_and Diu', 'name': 'Daman_and Diu'}, {'data': [['diu, Noun', 161]], 'id': 'Diu', 'name': 'Diu'}, {'data': [['beach, Noun', 112], ['is, Verb', 62], ['Dumas, Noun', 77], ['dumas, Noun', 149], ['me, Pronoun', 51], ['love, Noun', 53], ['I, Pronoun', 74], ['you, Pronoun', 62], ['fun, Noun', 114], ['surat, Noun', 57], ['friends, Noun', 51]], 'id': 'Dumas_Beach', 'name': 'Dumas_Beach'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Dwarka', 'name': 'Dwarka'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Elephanta_Caves', 'name': 'Elephanta_Caves'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Ghandhinagar', 'name': 'Ghandhinagar'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Gulbarga', 'name': 'Gulbarga'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Guntur', 'name': 'Guntur'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Jamnagar', 'name': 'Jamnagar'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Junagadh', 'name': 'Junagadh'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Kamshet', 'name': 'Kamshet'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Karimnagar', 'name': 'Karimnagar'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Karjat', 'name': 'Karjat'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Khandala_Lonavala', 'name': 'Khandala_Lonavala'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Kolad', 'name': 'Kolad'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Kurnool', 'name': 'Kurnool'}, {'data': [['Lavasa, Noun', 149], ['india, Noun', 93], ['is, Verb', 64], ['love, Noun', 56], ['pune, Noun', 106], ['you, Pronoun', 56], ['lavasa, Noun', 415], ['fun, Noun', 61], ['lake, Noun', 53], ['friends, Noun', 54]], 'id': 'Lavassa', 'name': 'Lavassa'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Lohaghad_Fort', 'name': 'Lohaghad_Fort'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Mahabaleshwar', 'name': 'Mahabaleshwar'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Malshej_Ghat', 'name': 'Malshej_Ghat'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Malshejghat', 'name': 'Malshejghat'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Mandvi', 'name': 'Mandvi'}, {'data': [ ['travel, Noun', 52], ['matheran, Noun', 333], ['nature, Noun', 150], ['hills, Noun', 63], ['is, Verb', 63], ['maharashtra, Noun', 50], ['Matheran, Noun', 152], ['love, Noun', 56], ['trekking, Verb', 59], ['I, Pronoun', 53], ['you, Pronoun', 70], ['beautiful, Noun', 63], ['matherandiaries, Noun', 55], ['fun, Noun', 100], ['mountains, Noun', 51], ['friends, Noun', 70]], 'id': 'Matheran', 'name': 'Matheran'}, {'data': [ ['Abu, Noun', 79], ['mountabu, Noun', 126], ['is, Verb', 65], ['you, Pronoun', 82], ['abu, Noun', 78], ['I, Pronoun', 72], ['fun, Noun', 88], ['lake, Noun', 51], ['rajasthan, Noun', 57]], 'id': 'Mount_Abu', 'name': 'Mount_Abu'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Nagarjunasagar', 'name': 'Nagarjunasagar'}, {'data': [['travel, Noun', 56], ['Nashik, Noun', 118], ['love, Noun', 72], ['I, Pronoun', 81], ['india, Noun', 95], ['nasik, Noun', 96], ['you, Pronoun', 73], ['instagood, Noun', 56], ['India, Noun', 73], ['is, Verb', 97], ['nashik, Noun', 139], ['fun, Noun', 66], ['Nasik, Noun', 76]], 'id': 'Nashik', 'name': 'Nashik'}, {'data': [['travel, Noun', 56], ['Nashik, Noun', 118], ['love, Noun', 74], ['I, Pronoun', 81], ['india, Noun', 93], ['nasik, Noun', 96], ['you, Pronoun', 73], ['instagood, Noun', 56], ['India, Noun', 73], ['is, Verb', 97], ['nashik, Noun', 139], ['fun, Noun', 65],['Nasik, Noun', 76]], 'id': 'Nasik', 'name': 'Nasik'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Nizamabad', 'name': 'Nizamabad'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Palanpur', 'name': 'Palanpur'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Palitana', 'name': 'Palitana'}, {'data': [['me, Pronoun', 55], ['india, Noun', 50], ['nature, Noun', 76], ['is, Verb', 55], ['love, Noun', 61], ['mahabaleshwar, Noun', 128], ['panchgani, Noun', 149], ['Panchgani, Noun', 65], ['you, Pronoun', 86], ['Mahabaleshwar, Noun', 65], ['I, Pronoun', 79], ['fun, Noun', 63], ['instalike, Noun', 52], ['friends, Noun', 53]], 'id': 'Panchgani', 'name': 'Panchgani'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Pawna_Lake', 'name': 'Pawna_Lake'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Porbandar', 'name': 'Porbandar'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Rani_Ki Vav', 'name': 'Rani_Ki Vav'}, {'data': [['saputara, Noun', 136], ['Saputara, Noun', 70], ['fun, Noun', 50]], 'id': 'Saputara', 'name': 'Saputara'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Satara', 'name': 'Satara'}, {'data': [['Shirdi, Noun', 92], ['shirdi, Noun', 142]], 'id': 'Shirdi', 'name': 'Shirdi'}, {'data': [['silvassa, Noun', 50]], 'id': 'Silvassa', 'name': 'Silvassa'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Sinhaghad', 'name': 'Sinhaghad'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Somnath', 'name': 'Somnath'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Srisailam', 'name': 'Srisailam'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'Surendranagar', 'name': 'Surendranagar'}, {'data': [['baroda, Noun', 54], ['love, Noun', 53], ['vadodara, Noun', 96], ['garba, Noun', 87], ['is, Verb', 60], ['you, Pronoun', 53], ['instadaily, Adverb', 51], ['friends, Noun', 68], ['me, Pronoun', 50], ['fun, Noun', 110], ['day, Noun', 54], ['instagood, Noun', 70],  ['navratri, Noun', 87], ['Navratri, Noun', 72]], 'id': 'Vadodara', 'name': 'Vadodara'}, {'data': [], 'id': 'wai_maharashtra', 'name': 'wai_maharashtra'}, {'data': [{'y': 15, 'drilldown': u'Alibaug', 'name': u'Alibaug'}, {'y': 5, 'drilldown': u'Karjat', 'name': u'Karjat'}, {'y': 31, 'drilldown': u'Matheran', 'name': u'Matheran'}, {'y': 1, 'drilldown': u'Kamshet', 'name': u'Kamshet'}, {'y': 23, 'drilldown': u'Lavassa', 'name': u'Lavassa'}], 'id': 'group_1', 'name': 'group_1'}, {'data': [{'y': 1, 'drilldown': u'Sinhaghad', 'name': u'Sinhaghad'}, {'y': 30, 'drilldown': u'Panchgani', 'name': u'Panchgani'}, {'y': 1, 'drilldown': u'Kolad', 'name': u'Kolad'}, {'y': 1, 'drilldown': u'Satara', 'name': u'Satara'}, {'y': 1, 'drilldown': u'Mahabaleshwar', 'name': u'Mahabaleshwar'}, {'y': 1, 'drilldown': u'Bhandardara', 'name': u'Bhandardara'}, {'y': 12, 'drilldown': u'Shirdi', 'name': u'Shirdi'}, {'y': 32, 'drilldown': u'Nashik', 'name': u'Nashik'}], 'id': 'group_2', 'name': 'group_2'}, {'data': [{'y': 1, 'drilldown': u'Daman', 'name': u'Daman'}, {'y': 11, 'drilldown': u'Diu', 'name': u'Diu'}, {'y': 29, 'drilldown': u'Vadodara', 'name': u'Vadodara'}, {'y': 11, 'drilldown': u'Saputara', 'name': u'Saputara'}, {'y': 8, 'drilldown': u'Silvassa', 'name': u'Silvassa'}, {'y': 32, 'drilldown': u'Nasik', 'name': u'Nasik'}, {'y': 12, 'drilldown': u'Shirdi', 'name': u'Shirdi'}, {'y': 1, 'drilldown': u'Malshejghat', 'name': u'Malshejghat'}], 'id': 'group_3', 'name': 'group_3'}, {'data': [{'y': 29, 'drilldown': u'Vadodara', 'name': u'Vadodara'}, {'y': 1, 'drilldown': u'Palitana', 'name': u'Palitana'}, {'y': 1, 'drilldown': u'Ghandhinagar', 'name': u'Ghandhinagar'}, {'y': 1, 'drilldown': u'Surendranagar', 'name': u'Surendranagar'}, {'y': 1, 'drilldown': u'Palanpur', 'name': u'Palanpur'}, {'y': 5, 'drilldown': u'Bhavnagar', 'name': u'Bhavnagar'}, {'y': 1, 'drilldown': u'Anand', 'name': u'Anand'}, {'y': 1, 'drilldown': u'Adalaj', 'name': u'Adalaj'}], 'id': 'group_4', 'name': 'group_4'}, {'data': [{'y': 1, 'drilldown': u'Bidar', 'name': u'Bidar'}, {'y': 1, 'drilldown': u'Nagarjunasagar', 'name': u'Nagarjunasagar'}, {'y': 1, 'drilldown': u'Nizamabad', 'name': u'Nizamabad'}, {'y': 1, 'drilldown': u'Karimnagar', 'name': u'Karimnagar'}, {'y': 1, 'drilldown': u'Srisailam', 'name': u'Srisailam'}, {'y': 1, 'drilldown': u'Guntur', 'name': u'Guntur'}, {'y': 1, 'drilldown': u'Kurnool', 'name': u'Kurnool'}, {'y': 1, 'drilldown': u'Gulbarga', 'name': u'Gulbarga'}], 'id': 'group_5', 'name': 'group_5'}, {'data': [{'y': 1, 'drilldown': u'Jamnagar', 'name': u'Jamnagar'}, {'y': 3, 'drilldown': u'Junagadh', 'name': u'Junagadh'}, {'y': 1, 'drilldown': u'Palitana', 'name': u'Palitana'}, {'y': 1, 'drilldown': u'Porbandar', 'name': u'Porbandar'}, {'y': 1, 'drilldown': u'Somnath', 'name': u'Somnath'}, {'y': 1, 'drilldown': u'Dwarka', 'name': u'Dwarka'}, {'y': 1, 'drilldown': u'Mandvi', 'name': u'Mandvi'}, {'y': 31, 'drilldown': u'Bhuj', 'name': u'Bhuj'}], 'id': 'group_6', 'name': 'group_6'}], 'location': [{'y': 9, 'drilldown': 'group_1', 'name': 'group_1'}, {'y': 10, 'drilldown': 'group_2', 'name': 'group_2'}, {'y': 10, 'drilldown': 'group_3', 'name': 'group_3'}, {'y': 10, 'drilldown': 'group_4', 'name': 'group_4'}, {'y': 10, 'drilldown': 'group_5', 'name': 'group_5'}, {'y': 10, 'drilldown': 'group_6', 'name': 'group_6'}], 'pie': [{'color': '#62E250', 'category': [{'color': '#42036F', 'category': [{'color': '#42036F', 'value': '130, Noun', 'label': 'beach'}, {'color': '#42036F', 'value': '82', 'label': ','}, {'color': '#42036F', 'value': '138', 'label': '.'}, {'color': '#42036F', 'value': '106', 'label': 'the'}, {'color': '#42036F', 'value': '67', 'label': 'and'}, {'color': '#42036F', 'value': '63, Noun', 'label': 'alibag'}, {'color': '#42036F', 'value': '60', 'label': 'to'}, {'color': '#42036F', 'value': '103', 'label': '!'}, {'color': '#42036F', 'value': '62', 'label': 'a'}, {'color': '#42036F', 'value': '73, Noun', 'label': 'fun'}, {'color': '#42036F', 'value': '70', 'label': '...'}, {'color': '#42036F', 'value': '50', 'label': ':'}, {'color': '#42036F', 'value': '65, Noun', 'label': 'alibaug'}, {'color': '#42036F', 'value': '4284', 'label': '#'}], 'value': '15', 'label': 'Alibaug'}, {'color': '#53D144', 'category': [{'color': '#53D144', 'value': '42', 'label': '#'}], 'value': '1', 'label': 'Kamshet'}, {'color': '#FC4693', 'category': [{'color': '#FC4693', 'value': '82', 'label': '.'}, {'color': '#FC4693', 'value': '52', 'label': '...'}, {'color': '#FC4693', 'value': '72', 'label': 'the'}, {'color': '#FC4693', 'value': '84', 'label': '!'}, {'color': '#FC4693', 'value': '2270', 'label': '#'}], 'value': '5', 'label': 'Karjat'}, {'color': '#D5D134', 'category': [ {'color': '#D5D134', 'value': '149, Noun', 'label': 'Lavasa'}, {'color': '#D5D134', 'value': '93, Noun', 'label': 'india'}, {'color': '#D5D134', 'value': '127', 'label': ','}, {'color': '#D5D134', 'value': '153', 'label': '.'}, {'color': '#D5D134', 'value': '123', 'label': '...'}, {'color': '#D5D134', 'value': '64, Verb', 'label': 'is'}, {'color': '#D5D134', 'value': '53', 'label': 'in'}, {'color': '#D5D134', 'value': '138', 'label': 'the'}, {'color': '#D5D134', 'value': '56, Noun', 'label': 'love'}, {'color': '#D5D134', 'value': '106, Noun', 'label': 'pune'}, {'color': '#D5D134', 'value': '55', 'label': ':'}, {'color': '#D5D134', 'value': '66', 'label': 'of'}, {'color': '#D5D134', 'value': '53', 'label': 'with'}, {'color': '#D5D134', 'value': '56, Pronoun', 'label': 'you'}, {'color': '#D5D134', 'value': '91', 'label': 'to'}, {'color': '#D5D134', 'value': '175', 'label': '!'}, {'color': '#D5D134', 'value': '99', 'label': 'a'}, {'color': '#D5D134', 'value': '415, Noun', 'label': 'lavasa'}, {'color': '#D5D134', 'value': '61, Noun', 'label': 'fun'}, {'color': '#D5D134', 'value': '7250', 'label': '#'}, {'color': '#D5D134', 'value': '53, Noun', 'label': 'lake'}, {'color': '#D5D134', 'value': '54, Noun', 'label': 'friends'}], 'value': '23', 'label': 'Lavassa'}, {'color': '#75764D', 'category': [{'color': '#75764D', 'value': '52, Noun', 'label': 'travel'}, {'color': '#75764D', 'value': '136', 'label': ','}, {'color': '#75764D', 'value': '333, Noun', 'label': 'matheran'}, {'color': '#75764D', 'value': '150, Noun', 'label': 'nature'}, {'color': '#75764D', 'value': '63, Noun', 'label': 'hills'}, {'color': '#75764D', 'value': '189', 'label': '.'}, {'color': '#75764D', 'value': '63, Verb', 'label': 'is'}, {'color': '#75764D', 'value': '68', 'label': 'in'}, {'color': '#75764D', 'value': '140', 'label': 'the'}, {'color': '#75764D', 'value': '50, Noun', 'label': 'maharashtra'}, {'color': '#75764D', 'value': '152, Noun', 'label': 'Matheran'}, {'color': '#75764D', 'value': '56, Noun', 'label': 'love'}, {'color': '#75764D', 'value': '59, Verb', 'label': 'trekking'}, {'color': '#75764D', 'value': '82', 'label': 'and'}, {'color': '#75764D', 'value': '53, Pronoun', 'label': 'I'}, {'color': '#75764D', 'value': '112', 'label': 'of'}, {'color': '#75764D', 'value': '50', 'label': 'with'}, {'color': '#75764D', 'value': '50', 'label': 'at'}, {'color': '#75764D', 'value': '70, Pronoun', 'label': 'you'}, {'color': '#75764D', 'value': '118', 'label': 'to'}, {'color': '#75764D', 'value': '63, Noun', 'label': 'beautiful'}, {'color': '#75764D', 'value': '148', 'label': '!'}, {'color': '#75764D', 'value': '107', 'label': 'a'}, {'color': '#75764D', 'value': '55, Noun', 'label': 'matherandiaries'}, {'color': '#75764D', 'value': '100, Noun', 'label': 'fun'}, {'color': '#75764D', 'value': '120', 'label': '...'}, {'color': '#75764D', 'value': '69', 'label': ':'}, {'color': '#75764D', 'value': '51, Noun', 'label': 'mountains'}, {'color': '#75764D', 'value': '7060', 'label': '#'}, {'color': '#75764D', 'value': '70, Noun', 'label': 'friends'}], 'value': '31', 'label': 'Matheran'}], 'value': 'group_1', 'label': 'group_1'}, {'color': '#BD4271', 'category': [{'color': '#036E39', 'category': [{'color': '#036E39', 'value': '277', 'label': '#'}], 'value': '1', 'label': 'Bhandardara'}, {'color': '#F65BEC', 'category': [{'color': '#F65BEC', 'value': '262', 'label': '#'}], 'value': '1', 'label': 'Kolad'}, {'color': '#FB8C3C', 'category': [{'color': '#FB8C3C', 'value': '471', 'label': '#'}], 'value': '1', 'label': 'Mahabaleshwar'}, {'color': '#542CD6', 'category': [{'color': '#542CD6', 'value': '56, Noun', 'label': 'travel'}, {'color': '#542CD6', 'value': '118, Noun', 'label': 'Nashik'}, {'color': '#542CD6', 'value': '267', 'label': '.'}, {'color': '#542CD6', 'value': '74', 'label': 'for'}, {'color': '#542CD6', 'value': '72, Noun', 'label': 'love'}, {'color': '#542CD6', 'value': '81, Pronoun', 'label': 'I'}, {'color': '#542CD6', 'value': '74', 'label': 'with'}, {'color': '#542CD6', 'value': '141', 'label': 'to'}, {'color': '#542CD6', 'value': '8587', 'label': '#'}, {'color': '#542CD6', 'value': '204', 'label': ':'}, {'color': '#542CD6', 'value': '95, Noun', 'label': 'india'}, {'color': '#542CD6', 'value': '96, Noun', 'label': 'nasik'}, {'color': '#542CD6', 'value': '246', 'label': 'the'}, {'color': '#542CD6', 'value': '73, Pronoun', 'label': 'you'}, {'color': '#542CD6', 'value': '56, Noun', 'label': 'instagood'}, {'color': '#542CD6', 'value': '133', 'label': 'a'}, {'color': '#542CD6', 'value': '203', 'label': '...'}, {'color': '#542CD6', 'value': '63', 'label': '('}, {'color': '#542CD6', 'value': '245', 'label': ','}, {'color': '#542CD6', 'value': '73, Noun', 'label': 'India'}, {'color': '#542CD6', 'value': '97, Verb', 'label': 'is'}, {'color': '#542CD6', 'value': '182', 'label': 'in'}, {'color': '#542CD6', 'value': '228', 'label': '!'}, {'color': '#542CD6', 'value': '139, Noun', 'label': 'nashik'}, {'color': '#542CD6', 'value': '66, Noun', 'label': 'fun'}, {'color': '#542CD6', 'value': '96', 'label': ')'}, {'color': '#542CD6', 'value': '66', 'label': 'my'}, {'color': '#542CD6', 'value': '76, Noun', 'label': 'Nasik'}, {'color': '#542CD6', 'value': '88', 'label': 'and'}, {'color': '#542CD6', 'value': '55', 'label': 'on'}, {'color': '#542CD6', 'value': '163', 'label': 'of'}], 'value': '32', 'label': 'Nashik'}, {'color': '#4EE3FD', 'category': [{'color': '#4EE3FD', 'value': '55, Pronoun', 'label': 'me'}, {'color': '#4EE3FD', 'value': '55', 'label': 'my'}, {'color': '#4EE3FD', 'value': '50, Noun', 'label': 'india'}, {'color': '#4EE3FD', 'value': '154', 'label': ','}, {'color': '#4EE3FD', 'value': '76, Noun', 'label': 'nature'}, {'color': '#4EE3FD', 'value': '180', 'label': '.'}, {'color': '#4EE3FD', 'value': '55, Verb', 'label': 'is'}, {'color': '#4EE3FD', 'value': '94', 'label': 'in'}, {'color': '#4EE3FD', 'value': '197', 'label': 'the'}, {'color': '#4EE3FD', 'value': '59', 'label': 'for'}, {'color': '#4EE3FD', 'value': '61, Noun', 'label': 'love'}, {'color': '#4EE3FD', 'value': '128, Noun', 'label': 'mahabaleshwar'}, {'color': '#4EE3FD', 'value': '75', 'label': 'and'}, {'color': '#4EE3FD', 'value': '149, Noun', 'label': 'panchgani'}, {'color': '#4EE3FD', 'value': '65, Noun', 'label': 'Panchgani'}, {'color': '#4EE3FD', 'value': '102', 'label': 'of'}, {'color': '#4EE3FD', 'value': '58', 'label': 'with'}, {'color': '#4EE3FD', 'value': '86, Pronoun', 'label': 'you'}, {'color': '#4EE3FD', 'value': '65, Noun', 'label': 'Mahabaleshwar'}, {'color': '#4EE3FD', 'value': '109', 'label': 'to'}, {'color': '#4EE3FD', 'value': '199', 'label': '!'}, {'color': '#4EE3FD', 'value': '85', 'label': 'a'}, {'color': '#4EE3FD', 'value': '79, Pronoun', 'label': 'I'}, {'color': '#4EE3FD', 'value': '6558', 'label': '#'}, {'color': '#4EE3FD', 'value': '63, Noun', 'label': 'fun'}, {'color': '#4EE3FD', 'value': '177', 'label': '...'}, {'color': '#4EE3FD', 'value': '52, Noun', 'label': 'instalike'}, {'color': '#4EE3FD', 'value': '50', 'label': ':'}, {'color': '#4EE3FD', 'value': '53, Noun', 'label': 'friends'}], 'value': '30', 'label': 'Panchgani'}, {'color': '#123441', 'category': [{'color': '#123441', 'value': '99', 'label': '#'}], 'value': '1', 'label': 'Satara'}, {'color': '#F022EE', 'category': [{'color': '#F022EE', 'value': '92, Noun, Noun', 'label': 'Shirdi'}, {'color': '#F022EE', 'value': '79', 'label': ','}, {'color': '#F022EE', 'value': '124', 'label': '.'}, {'color': '#F022EE', 'value': '87', 'label': 'the'}, {'color': '#F022EE', 'value': '142, Noun, Noun', 'label': 'shirdi'}, {'color': '#F022EE', 'value': '67', 'label': 'of'}, {'color': '#F022EE', 'value': '58', 'label': 'with'}, {'color': '#F022EE', 'value': '68', 'label': 'to'}, {'color': '#F022EE', 'value': '153', 'label': '!'}, {'color': '#F022EE', 'value': '58', 'label': 'a'}, {'color': '#F022EE', 'value': '3254', 'label': '#'}, {'color': '#F022EE', 'value': '85', 'label': '...'}], 'value': '12', 'label': 'Shirdi'}, {'color': '#38DB7F', 'category': [{'color': '#38DB7F', 'value': '3', 'label': '#'}], 'value': '1', 'label': 'Sinhaghad'}], 'value': 'group_2', 'label': 'group_2'}, {'color': '#634AEE', 'category': [{'color': '#BBDB1B', 'category': [{'color': '#BBDB1B', 'value': '39', 'label': '#'}], 'value': '1', 'label': 'Daman'}, {'color': '#635F8A', 'category': [{'color': '#635F8A', 'value': '88', 'label': ','}, {'color': '#635F8A', 'value': '58', 'label': 'in'}, {'color': '#635F8A', 'value': '102', 'label': 'the'}, {'color': '#635F8A', 'value': '3632', 'label': '#'}, {'color': '#635F8A', 'value': '161, Noun', 'label': 'diu'}, {'color': '#635F8A', 'value': '63', 'label': 'to'}, {'color': '#635F8A', 'value': '59', 'label': '!'}, {'color': '#635F8A', 'value': '71', 'label': '...'}, {'color': '#635F8A', 'value': '66', 'label': 'of'}, {'color': '#635F8A', 'value': '131', 'label': '.'}], 'value': '11', 'label': 'Diu'}, {'color': '#17998C', 'category': [{'color': '#17998C', 'value': '1791', 'label': '#'}], 'value': '1', 'label': 'Malshejghat'}, {'color': '#61490A', 'category': [{'color': '#61490A', 'value': '56, Noun', 'label': 'travel'}, {'color': '#61490A', 'value': '118, Noun', 'label': 'Nashik'}, {'color': '#61490A', 'value': '265', 'label': '.'}, {'color': '#61490A', 'value': '73', 'label': 'for'}, {'color': '#61490A', 'value': '74, Noun', 'label': 'love'}, {'color': '#61490A', 'value': '81, Pronoun', 'label': 'I'}, {'color': '#61490A', 'value': '75', 'label': 'with'}, {'color': '#61490A', 'value': '142', 'label': 'to'}, {'color': '#61490A', 'value': '8537', 'label': '#'}, {'color': '#61490A', 'value': '205', 'label': ':'}, {'color': '#61490A', 'value': '93, Noun', 'label': 'india'}, {'color': '#61490A', 'value': '96, Noun', 'label': 'nasik'}, {'color': '#61490A', 'value': '245', 'label': 'the'}, {'color': '#61490A', 'value': '73, Pronoun', 'label': 'you'}, {'color': '#61490A', 'value': '56, Noun', 'label': 'instagood'}, {'color': '#61490A', 'value': '133', 'label': 'a'}, {'color': '#61490A', 'value': '202', 'label': '...'}, {'color': '#61490A', 'value': '63', 'label': '('}, {'color': '#61490A', 'value': '244', 'label': ','}, {'color': '#61490A', 'value': '73, Noun', 'label': 'India'}, {'color': '#61490A', 'value': '97, Verb', 'label': 'is'}, {'color': '#61490A', 'value': '181', 'label': 'in'}, {'color': '#61490A', 'value': '227', 'label': '!'}, {'color': '#61490A', 'value': '139, Noun', 'label': 'nashik'}, {'color': '#61490A', 'value': '65, Noun', 'label': 'fun'}, {'color': '#61490A', 'value': '97', 'label': ')'},  {'color': '#61490A', 'value': '65', 'label': 'my'}, {'color': '#61490A', 'value': '76, Noun', 'label': 'Nasik'}, {'color': '#61490A', 'value': '87', 'label': 'and'}, {'color': '#61490A', 'value': '55', 'label': 'on'}, {'color': '#61490A', 'value': '162', 'label': 'of'}], 'value': '32', 'label': 'Nasik'}, {'color': '#C83E79', 'category': [{'color': '#C83E79', 'value': '136, Noun', 'label': 'saputara'}, {'color': '#C83E79', 'value': '66', 'label': ','}, {'color': '#C83E79', 'value': '77', 'label': '.'}, {'color': '#C83E79', 'value': '67', 'label': 'the'}, {'color': '#C83E79', 'value': '70, Noun', 'label': 'Saputara'}, {'color': '#C83E79', 'value': '54', 'label': 'to'}, {'color': '#C83E79', 'value': '86', 'label': '!'}, {'color': '#C83E79', 'value': '50, Noun', 'label': 'fun'}, {'color': '#C83E79', 'value': '122', 'label': '...'}, {'color': '#C83E79', 'value': '3862', 'label': '#'}], 'value': '11', 'label': 'Saputara'}, {'color': '#F022EE', 'category': [{'color': '#F022EE', 'value': '92, Noun, Noun', 'label': 'Shirdi'}, {'color': '#F022EE', 'value': '79', 'label': ','}, {'color': '#F022EE', 'value': '124', 'label': '.'}, {'color': '#F022EE', 'value': '87', 'label': 'the'}, {'color': '#F022EE', 'value': '142, Noun, Noun', 'label': 'shirdi'}, {'color': '#F022EE', 'value': '67', 'label': 'of'}, {'color': '#F022EE', 'value': '58', 'label': 'with'}, {'color': '#F022EE', 'value': '68', 'label': 'to'}, {'color': '#F022EE', 'value': '153', 'label': '!'}, {'color': '#F022EE', 'value': '58', 'label': 'a'}, {'color': '#F022EE', 'value': '3254', 'label': '#'}, {'color': '#F022EE', 'value': '85', 'label': '...'}], 'value': '12', 'label': 'Shirdi'}, {'color': '#F5B485', 'category': [{'color': '#F5B485', 'value': '83', 'label': ','}, {'color': '#F5B485', 'value': '107', 'label': '.'}, {'color': '#F5B485', 'value': '91', 'label': 'the'}, {'color': '#F5B485', 'value': '50, Noun', 'label': 'silvassa'}, {'color': '#F5B485', 'value': '58', 'label': 'to'}, {'color': '#F5B485', 'value': '109', 'label': '!'}, {'color': '#F5B485', 'value': '3580', 'label': '#'}, {'color': '#F5B485', 'value': '58', 'label': '...'}], 'value': '8', 'label': 'Silvassa'}, {'color': '#9C5061', 'category': [{'color': '#9C5061', 'value': '217', 'label': '.'}, {'color': '#9C5061', 'value': '54, Noun, Noun', 'label': 'baroda'}, {'color': '#9C5061', 'value': '67', 'label': 'for'}, {'color': '#9C5061', 'value': '53, Noun, Noun', 'label': 'love'}, {'color': '#9C5061', 'value': '96, Noun, Noun', 'label': 'vadodara'}, {'color': '#9C5061', 'value': '59', 'label': 'with'}, {'color': '#9C5061', 'value': '103', 'label': 'to'}, {'color': '#9C5061', 'value': '6846', 'label': '#'}, {'color': '#9C5061', 'value': '87, Noun, Noun', 'label': 'garba'}, {'color': '#9C5061', 'value': '60, Verb, Verb', 'label': 'is'}, {'color': '#9C5061', 'value': '75', 'label': 'in'}, {'color': '#9C5061', 'value': '158', 'label': 'the'}, {'color': '#9C5061', 'value': '53, Pronoun, Pronoun', 'label': 'you'}, {'color': '#9C5061', 'value': '72', 'label': 'a'}, {'color': '#9C5061', 'value': '208', 'label': '...'}, {'color': '#9C5061', 'value': '51, Adverb, Adverb', 'label': 'instadaily'}, {'color': '#9C5061', 'value': '68, Noun, Noun', 'label': 'friends'}, {'color': '#9C5061', 'value': '162', 'label': ','}, {'color': '#9C5061', 'value': '50, Pronoun, Pronoun', 'label': 'me'}, {'color': '#9C5061', 'value': '239', 'label': '!'}, {'color': '#9C5061', 'value': '110, Noun, Noun', 'label': 'fun'}, {'color': '#9C5061', 'value': '54, Noun, Noun', 'label': 'day'}]}";
            console.log(response);
            response = JSON.parse(response)// Internationalization
            response_tree = response["tree"]
            response_location = response["location"]
```

which gives error :

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

Comment: your response string is invalid JSON for a start

Comment: can you please elaborate? invalid by syntex?

Comment: yes, invalid syntax ... you need to change all `'` to `"` - plus about 1/5th of the way in, you start having values like `'drilldown': u'Gulbarga'` - what is the u doing there?

Comment: @JaromandaX: I added the same string which I received in console response and one which gives result. But when I add it manually, it gives error

Comment: it's not valid JSON so JSON.parse wont work, simple

Answer (score 0):

The value assigned to 'response' is not a proper JSON format, just a part shown below with proper format:

```
  response = {'tree': [{'data':   
  [], 'id': 'Adalaj', 'name': 'Adalaj'}]};
```

//Do the rest, it's already a JSON object, no need to parse - so JSON.parse(response) throws error.